# MySQL how to get only the user name from user information column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column in my table that looks like this:

```
order_user
................................................
user@emial.com¬firstname lastname¬¬0888888848¬¬¬
```

Is there a query that can get only the first and last name and ignore everything else?

Comment: What is `¬`? a tab?  String manipulation required.  use `mid()` and `instr()` to find first '¬' then take that until the next occurance of ¬

Comment: And do all rows have the same format? Otherwise, 1 example is not enough.

Comment: @xQbert It seems to be a symbol that is used to separate the email from the name and the name from the number.

Comment: @underscore_d Yes all of them have the same format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this task using `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`

```
select substring_index(substring_index(order_user,"¬",2),"¬",-1) as Username
 from yourTablename;
```

The SUBSTRING_INDEX() function returns the substring of string before number of occurrences of delimiter.

For more info, [Click here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

Feel free to ask doubt(s), if you have any.

Comment: Explanation of substring_index would help this answer or a [Doc link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)  Code only answers while may solve the immediate need, do not educate others as to why this answer works.  However, good use of `substring_index()`.